# Cardinality of a totally ordered union

Tags: set-theory, cardinals

Let $(X_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in A}, (Y_{\alpha})_{\alpha \in A}$ be families of sets such that for $\{X_{\alpha} \mid \alpha \in A \}$ and $\{Y_{\alpha} \mid \alpha \in A \}$ are totally ordered by inclusion. We have $(X_{\alpha},Y_{\alpha}) \neq (X_{\beta},Y_{\beta})$ for $\alpha \neq \beta$. Suppose that $|X_{\alpha}| \leq |Y_{\alpha}|$ for any $\alpha \in A$. It is true that $|\bigcup_{\alpha} X_{\alpha}| \leq |\bigcup_{\alpha} Y_{\alpha}|$?

Comment: Does "totally ordered by inclusion" mean that $X_0$ is a **proper** subset of $X_1$ or does it just mean that $X_0\subseteq X_1$?

Comment: @bof Well, I assumed that $X_{\alpha} \neq X_{\beta}$ for $\alpha \neq \beta$ (and similarly for $Y$).

Comment: In that case it looks like an easy "yes". To start with, we can assume $A$ is well-ordered, can't we?

Comment: By the way, you should put that assumption in the question, because it's **not** clear from what you wrote, and it drastically changes the meaning.

Comment: @bof Sorry, edited again. Initial comment was wrong.

Comment: @bof Dear bof, I'm sorry to bother you, but you seemed to have some ideas regarding a case which might be similar to my later question. I would be grateful if you could visit this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3366187/a-proof-in-module-theory-a-set-theoretic-consideration-bigcup-i-in-i-b-i

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  For instance, let $A=\omega_1$, let $X_\alpha=\alpha$, and let $Y_\alpha=\omega$ for all $\alpha$.  Then $|X_\alpha|\leq|Y_\alpha|$ for all $\alpha$ since $X_\alpha=\alpha$ is always countable but $\bigcup X_\alpha=\omega_1$ has larger cardinality than $\bigcup Y_\alpha=\omega$.

Comment: From the comments it seems clear that, in spite of how it is written in the question, the assumption is that  if $\alpha\ne\beta$ are in $A$, then $X_\alpha\ne X_\beta$ *and* $Y_\alpha\ne Y_\beta$.

Comment: They later said their initial comment was wrong, though, after editing to the current version.