# A proof in module theory: a set theoretic consideration $|\bigcup_{i \in I} B_i| \leq |Y|$

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, modules, free-modules, well-orders

The set-theoretic result used in the proof I want to know about is the following:

> Let $(B_i)_{i \in I}$ be a family of sets such that, for all $i,j \in I$, either $B_i \subseteq B_j$ or $B_j \subseteq B_i$ holds and, for all $i \in I$, $|B_i| \leq |Y|$. Then $|\bigcup_{i \in I} B_i| \leq |Y|$.

Which conditions must be true (if any) for this to hold, and why? I tried to put a well-order on both $I$ and $Y$, but didn't succeed even with that. This seem to be implicitly assumed in the following proof (the book is *Abstract Algebra* by Grillet).

If this inequality is not true in the general case, I wonder if there is a condition in the proof that make it true.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It would be pleasant if you can state the hypothesis of the problem explicitly! In any case, if I understood, you are asking why $|\bigcup B_i| \leq |Y| $ whenever $|B_i| \le |Y|$ and $B_i \subseteq B_j$ whenever $i <j$. In this case, note that $|\bigcup B_i| = \sup |B_i| \le |Y|$

Comment: @AndreaMarino Oh, I'm sorry. It was in the title originally, but I edited and forgot to encorporate it in the body of the question. Will do in a moment.

Comment: @AndreaMarino Well, it appears we can index the set of such $B's$ by the trivial indexing where $I$ is the set of such $B$. The index set then will be partially ordered by inclusion, so your hypothesis would be correct: $B_i \subseteq B_j$ whenver $i \leq j$ (but without strict inequality). However, I would appreciate if you could eleborate on why $|\bigcup_{i \in I} B_i| = \sup_{i \in I} |B_i|$. I can't seem to find out the reason as of know. Clearly, $\sup_{i \in I} |B_i| \leq |\bigcup_{i \in I} B_i|$. But why we have the reserve inequality, I don't know.

Comment: I answered you below. Note that when you use a set of indices for a chain in Zorn, it is totally ordered, not only partially!

Comment: @AndreaMarino Not necessarily $|\bigcup B_i|=\sup |B_i|$. For instance, the first uncountable ordinal $\omega_1$ is a union of a well-ordered family of countable ordinals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claimed set-theoretic result is wrong. For instance, the first uncountable ordinal $\omega_1$ is a union of a well-ordered family of countable ordinals. So I guess that the proof contains a gap in the assurance that the family $\mathcal S$ is closed with respect to the unions of chains of its elements. Maybe it can be fixed by relaxing  condition $|B|\le |Y|$ for the family $\mathcal S$ and remarking in the last sentence of the proof that $Y=X$ implies $|B|\le |X|$.